# Many duplicates of the exact same question, is there anything that should be done?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I've found so many questions that say something along the lines of:

"Why is the first node of my Tor circuit always the same?"

For reference, here are 8 duplicate questions all asking about the same first node in the Tor circuit:

1. [Why is the first ip address Tor goes to the same one in Germany?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7048) [duplicate]
2. [In Tor Browser, I connect to the exact same entry node all the time, unable to change it](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9333) [duplicate]
3. [First Circuit Server Constant (New Identity)](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7197) [duplicate]
4. [First node always the same! Is that how it's supposed to work?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4099) **This is the original question because it was asked first**
5. [Same first node](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14617) [duplicate]
6. [why is this IP 69.172.212.42 locked in on circuit](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9625) [duplicate]
7. [Is my TOR installation compromised?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10444) [duplicate]
8. [Entry Node exactly the same for days. 100 request to change and remains same](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/10345) [duplicate]

I've marked 2 of them as duplicates (just today), but I was wanting to discuss with the others in this community about this issue. What should we do? Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the original questions. To me all seem to be duplicates. So it is perfectly right to close them as duplicates.

Some of the closed questions have answers which add to the existing answers. In such cases I tend to *merge* the questions. Merging is a task which you can do as a mod. So maybe the questions

1. [In Tor Browser, I connect to the exact same entry node all the time, unable to change it](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/9333/88)
2. [Entry Node exactly the same for days. 100 request to change and remains same](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/10345/88)

can be merged with the original question.

In a more general note: In my opinion there are lots of duplicate questions at our site. So it makes sense to look for them, look for the one with the best answer and close or merge the other questions. Maybe we can also coordinate our efforts here.

Comment: I am certainly willing to work with you to merge the questions. So it is fine to merge both questions you mentioned above with https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/why-is-the-first-ip-address-tor-goes-to-the-same-one-in-germany right?

Comment: With your approval, I'm fine with going ahead and merge both the questions in the answer you have said above.

Comment: Please do. ;-) If you have any questions or comments please feel free to ask. We could also try to chat in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124497/tor-moderation
Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Basically, I made https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4099 the original question and the others duplicates because this question was asked first, so it isn't a duplicate - the rest are. I've merged as many duplicates as I could, though I didn't merge all of them because only some of questions have answers that fit the original question perfectly. If you need anymore clarification on my actions, just ask me!

Comment: We can discuss this further in the moderators chat if you want to discuss further actions.